# Coldfusion - How to update Table Cells in Real time?

Tags: c#, coldfusion, websocket, coldfusion-10

I am relatively new to ColdFusion (using ColdFusion 10) and I have a question regarding creating a real-time updated table.

Currently I have a C# application that I have writing stock prices to a csv (text) file every 2 seconds and would like to reflect these changes as they happen in a table on web page. I know I could have the entire table refresh every 2 seconds, but this would generate a lot of requests to the server and I would like to know if there is a better way of doing it ? Could this be easily achieved using ColdFusion 10's new html5 Web-sockets functionality ?

Any advice/guidance on which way to proceed or how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated !

Thanks, AlanJames.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could rewrite your question and get at least 5 answers in first hour.

Now to answer it, if I understood well what you're asking.

IMHO websockets aren't there yet, if your website is for wide population and you are not 100% sure that they're coming with most recent Chrome or FF, forget it.

You could use some javascript websocket library which would gracefully fallback to flash or AJAX HTTP polling, like http://socket.io/ or cloud service like pusher.com . But this will complicate your life because you have 2-3 times more work in backend if you implement polling and websocket.

Regarding amount of requests, if you want real time data on screen, you gotta have server to support it.

You could optimize if you request once and refresh data for all the table, so not per cell. You'd get all new data at once and update those cells which changed with jquery. So not pulling all data again, or whole table HTML, just minimal amount of data.

AJAX polling would certainly help with amount of requests, time of the request being open is another possible problem though. You could do polling with BlazeDS which is even in ColdFusion 9.

some pages to look at:

http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2351-ColdFusion-10-Using-WebSockets-To-Push-A-Message-To-A-Target-User.htm

http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1956-Very-Simple-Pusher-And-ColdFusion-Powered-Chat.htm

http://nil.checksite.co.uk/index.cfm/2010/1/28/CF-BlazeDS-AJAX-LongPolling-Part1

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to answer Zarko.  Your answer is very informative.  While trying to find direction on this, I also came across HTML5 Server Sent Events which looks like it would be ideal for this situation as I only require information to flow in one direction, from the server to the client. The problem is again, as with websockets (as you point out above), unless you visitors have the latest browsers, it won't work !

Comment: I think I will probably go ahead and try using Server Sent Events and will fall back on Long Polling is the users browser doesn't support it. Here is some info on Server Sent Events if anyone is interested - http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/#toc-introduction  , http://html5doctor.com/server-sent-events/  , http://www.sagarganatra.com/2011/01/server-sent-events-with-html5-and.html

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to get live updates every 2 seconds without making some kind of request from your page to your server, otherwise how would it know if anything has changed?

Personally I would write a CFC method to read in your text file and see if it's changed, then poll that method every few seconds using jQuery to return whether it has changed or not, and pass back any updated content.

Without knowing the details of your text file etc. it's hard to write anything accurate. Fundamentally your CFC method would have to store (in a SESSION var probably) a copy of the text file data, so it could compare it with the latest read-in data and tell if anything has changed. If it has changed then send a structure back with the updates, or return a response saying it's unchanged.

Your CFC code would look something like this:

```
<cffunction name="check_update" access="remote" output="false">
    <cfset response = structNew()>
    <cffile action="read"
        file="path\to\your\textfile.txt" 
        variable="file_content"
    >
    <cfif file_content NEQ SESSION.file_content>
        <cfset response.updated = true>
        <cfset SESSION.file_content = file_content>
        <cfset response.content = structNew()>

        <!--- code here to populate 'content' variable with updated info --->

    <cfelse>
        <cfset response.updated = false>
    </cfif>
    <cfreturn response>
</cffunction>
```

Then the jQuery code to poll that data would look like this:

```
var update_interval;
var update_pause = 3000;

function check_update() {
    var request = {
        returnformat : 'json', 
        queryformat : 'column',
        method: 'check_update'
    }
    $.getJSON("path/to/your/service.cfc", request, function(data) {
        if(data.UPDATED == true) {
            /* code here to iterate through data.CONTENT */
            /* and render out your updated info to your table */
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    update_interval = setInterval(check_update(), update_pause);
});
```

So once the DOM is ready we create an interval that in this case fires every 3 seconds (3000ms) and calls the check_update() function. That function makes a call to your CFC, and checks the response. If the response UPDATED value is true then it runs whatever code to render your updates.

That's the most straightforward method of achieving what you need, and should work regardless of browser. In my experience the overhead of polling a CFC like that is really very small indeed and the amount of data you're transferring will by tiny, so it should be no problem to handle.

I don't think there's any other method that could be more lightweight / easy to put together. The benefits of long polling or SSE (with dodgy browser support) are negligible and not worth the programming overhead.

Thanks, Henry